# how to add a user in a dictionary?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this club command thing and what i want to do as the question stated is to add the users who does /create to the club = {} dictionary, Here is my code for reference.

```
club = {}
if message.content.lower().startswith('/create'):
    if message.author.id not in club:   
  #Here adds the user to the dictionary
        channel = bot.get_channel("467325363958317076")
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "What would you like to name your club? (Type /name *name is case-sensitive!*)")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "You already have a club!")  
    def check(msg):
        return msg.content.startswith('/name')

    message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, check=check)
    name = message.content[len('/name'):].strip()
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, '**{}** will be your club name!'.format(name))
    await bot.send_message(channel, "NAME: **{}**".format(name))
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "List down your current club members (type /member)")
if message.content.lower().startswith('/member'):
    if message.author.id not in club:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "")
    else:
        channel = bot.get_channel("467325363958317076")
        member = message.content[len('/member'):].strip()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, '**{}** will be your club members!'.format(member))
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "What is the subject of your club? Ex. Anime Club - Type /theme")
        await bot.send_message(channel, "Club Members **{}**".format(member))
```

Comment: You probably want `club['name'] = name` in your code (but I cannot read your mind of course) that way the empty `club` dictionary gets values. Do you want `channel` to be part of it too? You're free to add your entries.... At least you need the `id` to be part of it, because that's what you're testing for.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm a bit lost on what you said. By replacing `club = {}` to `club['name'] = name` in my code it will receive values correct? Now my question is how do i make the bot add the user who did the `/create` command to the dictionary?

Comment: Your `club` variable is in scope over all the code we see here, so all of this code (of the I suppose incomplete code) can modify it so that others see it too. What is a "club" in your data model : an array of id's of its members, or is there going to be more in it?

Comment: As for future preference probably more than just id's of members

Comment: Why use a dictionary if an array (of id's) would do as well? What are you going to do with the name of the member etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`club` should exist in an encompassing scope, probably at the module level of your bot.  That means the name `club` should be assigned once in your program, and then everything else just modifies that existing dictionary.

```
club = {}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith('/create'):
        if message.author.id in club:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "You already have a club!")  
            return   
        channel = bot.get_channel("467325363958317076")
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "What would you like to name your club? (Type /name *name is case-sensitive!*)")

        def check(msg):
            return msg.content.startswith('/name')

        message = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, check=check)
        name = message.content[len('/name'):].strip()

        club[message.author.id] = name

        await bot.send_message(message.channel, '**{}** will be your club name!'.format(name))
        await bot.send_message(channel, "NAME: **{}**".format(name))
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, "List down your current club members (type /member)")
```